# Find a string and get everything from string to next space

Tags: select, powershell, sed

I have a large textfile that I do some search and extract in today with the help of SED.
My current SED scrifp searches for a patters/string, and extract all info from the pattern/string to the next space.

I have just discoverd powershell and love it.

I have tried to replicate the same script in powershell with no success.
Does enyone have a suggestion how to do it?

Example from my current text file (hw.txt):

```
i1231 Cisco_1800 *IP=10.10.10.1 *SV=0 *NM=Router_1 *CM=remote_router_@site_1
i2385 Cisco_2960 *NM=switch_7 *CM=workstation_switch *IP=192.168.5.97 *SV=1
i8473 Cisco_PIX *IP=10.10.10.9 *SV=0 *NM=PIX_2 *CM=Int_Firewall
```

My Current SED script to extract *IP= and *NM=:

```
sed -ne "s/^.*\*IP=\([^ ]*\) .*\*NM=\([^ ]*\) .*$/\1 \2/p" -ne "s/^.*\*NM=\([^ ]    *\) .*\*IP=\([^ ]*\) .*$/\2 \1/p" db.tmp > hosts
```

The result with this script will be:

```
10.10.10.1 Router_1
192.168.5.97 switch_7
10.10.10.9 PIX_2
```

I have tried to use this as a simple way to get the syntax correct:

```
Select-String ".*\*nm=\([^ ]*\)" hw.txt
```

/Pierre

Comment: Your problem in translating the regex is that in `sed` you need to escape parentheses to change them from literal parens to capturing parens (same with braces and brackets, btw), instead of the other way around in .NET and most other regex flavors. But since PowerShell allows an even more elegant solution than a literal translation of your regex, I'll post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

First, create a regex object that will find IP and NM texts on a line of text, regardless of their order. In .NET, you can use named capturing groups, so no matter which of the two comes first, the matched text will be in the correct capturing group:

```
$regex = [regex] 
    @'
    (?x)\*IP=(?<IP>\S*).*?\*NM=(?<NM>\S*)  # IP first, NM second
    |                                      # or
    \*NM=(?<NM>\S*).*?\*IP=(?<IP>\S*)      # NM first, IP second
    '@
```

Then, you can iterate over your text and extract the values:

```
$match = $regex.Match($subject)
while ($match.Success) {
    IP = $match.Groups['IP'].Value
    NM = $match.Groups['NM'].Value
    $match = $match.NextMatch()
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!  So, It's not as easy as a one-liner. I'll give it a try. And if I want to add another pattern to extract then it seems to be fairly easy.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't get this to work. I'm probably getting this the wrong way. I get a error with the @'. It can't find the '@.?? How do I get the info from hw.txt? Get-content?

Comment: I'm sorry; I had RegexBuddy generate that PowerShell code snippet, and I can't say where the problem might be. Try it without the comments: `$regex = [regex] '\*IP=(?<IP>\S*).*?\*NM=(?<NM>\S*)|\*NM=(?<NM>\S*).*?\*IP=(?<IP>\S*)'` - does that work now?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
cat test.txt | select @{n='IP';e={[regex]::match($_,'\*IP=([^\s]+)').Groups[1].Value}},@{n='NM';e={[regex]::match($_,'\*NM=([^\s]+)').Groups[1].Value}}

IP           NM
--           --
10.10.10.1   Router_1
192.168.5.97 switch_7
10.10.10.9   PIX_2
```

To output the values with a space:

```
cat test.txt | foreach{
    $ip = [regex]::match($_,'\*IP=([^\s]+)').Groups[1].Value
    $nm = [regex]::match($_,'\*NM=([^\s]+)').Groups[1].Value
    "{0} {1}" -f $ip,$nm
}
```

Comment: That's dead simple. Thanks! Is there any way to just get a spce between the two groups`?

Comment: Thanks !!
Is it possible to have the script to do an AND instead of a OR between the *IP= and *NM=?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?